# How display value of part expression in MS Visual Studio in debug mode?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, debugging, netbeans

I have next C++ program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    string s = "abcde";
    int d = b*c + s.length() + a;
    return 0;
}
```

In NetBeans IDE in debug mode I can display subexpression value via
highlight text and mouseover it, like this:

[image]

How can I get the same functionality for MS Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit here seems to be the `s.length()` member function as it appears the [std::basic_string::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) value is not displayed on hover. Select the (sub)expression and drag to *Watch* window or right-click and choose *Add Watch*:
[image]

Usually you can achieve the same functionality in VS as in NetBeans IDE:
[image]